# Cypress reload page until element visible

Tags: cypress

I have following case:

After user uploads a file, there is a table report in the screen. The problem is: the table does not come up automatically, user needs to reload the page and if the file was already processed, the table is shown in screen, if it is still processing, user needs to wait a little bit and reload again.

How do I accomplish this task without using cy.wait() to wait an arbitrary time. I thought something like:

```
    cy.reload().should(() => {
        expect(document.querySelectorAll('table')).to.not.be.empty
    })
```

but didn't work

Comment: I don't think that repeats the `reload()`. Maybe `cy.wrap({}).should(() => { cy.reload(); expect(...`.

Comment: You can intercept the request which will fetch the required data and you can keep reloading until the expected data is received.

Answer (score 2):

If a `should()` assertion fails, Cypress only [repeats certain commands](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability.html#Commands-vs-assertions). As you have seen, `reload()` is not one of them.

I recommend using **recursion** to implement the repeating reload cycles. Here is an example:

```
let remainingAttempts = 30;

function waitUntilTableExists() {
    let $table = Cypress.$('table');
    if ($table.length) {
        // At least one table tag was found.
        // Return a jQuery object.
        return $table;
    }

    if (--remainingAttempts) {
        cy.log('Table not found yet. Remaining attempts: ' + remainingAttempts);

        // Requesting the page to reload (F5)
        cy.reload();

        // Wait a second for the server to respond and the DOM to be present.
        return cy.wait(1000).then(() => {
            return waitUntilTableExists();
        });
    }
    throw Error('Table was not found.');
}

waitUntilTableExists().then($table => {
    cy.log('table: ' + $table.text());
});
```

You may be tempted to use a `for` or `while` loop, but that won't work with Cypress. This is because most commands are not executed right away. Instead, [commands are asynchronous](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Commands-Are-Asynchronous).

Comment: Did not get it, all commands in test executed before test startup. How to use this in test ?

Comment: Every test is defined by the `it` function call. As a second param, `it` takes a closure. I would put the code above within the closure that is given to that `it` function call. Adjust selectors unless you happen to also wait for a `<table>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the wait on the reload using recursion. Something like this:

```
function reloadPageUntilReportIsGenerated(maxAttempts=10, attempts=0) {
    if (attempts > maxAttempts) {
        throw new Error("Timed out waiting for report to be generated")
    }
    cy.get("table").then($table => {
        if ($table.children().length == 0) {  // do your condition check synchronously
            cy.reload()
            reloadPageUntilReportIsGenerated(maxAttempts, attempts+1)
        }
    })
}
```

Then in the test call the wait right after you trigger the loading of the report.

```
cy.get("trigger-report").click()  // Start report generation
reloadPageUntilReportIsGenerated()  // Wait until page has report ready
```

The main caveat to watch out for is the recursive waiting requires mixing asynchronous and synchronous code, so be careful or you'll end up with the synchronous code running in the wrong place (like right as the test begins). Avoid this by wrapping any synchronous calls inside the asynchronous ones using `.then()`.